# What is the most convenient way to generate datetime in SQL?

Tags: mysql

SQL beginner here !

What is the most convenient way to create datetime objects within an SQL function, especially generating a datetime object for a given day, month, and year?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL

```
CAST('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss:uuuuuu' AS datetime)
```

where:
YYYY: Year
MM  : Month
DD  : Day
hh  : Hour
mm  : Minutes
ss  : Seconds
uuuuuu : Microseconds

**EDIT: I changed from mmm (miliseconds) to uuuuuu (microseconds) since MySQL suports 6 digits**

Answer (score 5):

Everything you want to know about MySQL datetime functions is [right here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html).  Well, probably most everything.

Answer (score 0):

Given a datetime column: `INSERT INTO Table ('datetime_column') VALUES (CURDATE( ))`

Given a timestamp: `INSERT INTO Table ('timestamp_column') VALUES (CURTIME())`

Using unix time: `INSERT INTO Table ('timestamp_column') VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP())`